# Загрузка данных из шаблона golang

Tags: golang, cookie

Всем привет.
Есть html файл login.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Так же есть фрагмент кода golang

```
//Выводится форма в которую вводится текст и этот текст возвращается в вызывающую функцию
func GetFormText(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) string {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "./login.html")
    details := DataFromHTML{
        Name1: r.FormValue("name"),
    }
    return details.Name1
}

//проверка что введено в поле(что вернул GetFormText)
func CheckName(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) bool {
    if GetFormText(w, r) == "text" {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}


//если CheckName вернул true то нужно установить куку
func Condition(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if CheckName(w, r) {//с этим условием кука не ставится
        cookie := http.Cookie{Name: "Name", Value: "Some"}
        http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
    }
}
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/data", Condition)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8181", nil)
}
```

Как и указано в комментарии кука не ставится при проверке CheckName, хотя если вместо установки куки будет другой код то он выполняется без проблем и если убрать условие то кука ставится без проблем. Никак не могу догнать, почему не выходит поставить куку.

Comment: может у вас условие не выполняется? вы дебажили?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

перед тем, как доставать данные из формы(`r.FormValue("name")`) надо ее распарсить

```
if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "ParseForm() err: %v", err)
    return ""
}
```

но возникает другая проблема. когда страницу загружаем в первый раз, то мы делаем GET запрос, а когда заполнили форму, нам надо делать POST запрос. проблема в том, что это один и тот же хэндлер обрабатывает.

можно отследать какого типа запрос, чтобы определить поведение. например, так

```
func GetFormText(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) string {
    switch r.Method {
    case "GET":
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "./login.html")
    case "POST":
        if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "ParseForm() err: %v", err)
            return ""
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Post from website! r.PostFrom = %v\n", r.PostForm)
        name := r.FormValue("name")
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Name = %s\n", name)
        return name
    default:
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Sorry, only GET and POST methods are supported.")
    }

    return ""
}
```

Comment: В очередной раз помогли))Разобрался. Все наладил с помощью вашего совета. Еще конечно посидел чтобы составить правильное условие, затем получил неопределенное поведение но в конечном итоге все решил и теперь работает как нужно. Правда я пока что исключаю обработку err, поэтому все ваши ответы "парсятся" у меня в голове и извлекается только то что нужно, думаю мне это пока что только засорит код, так как это учебный "проект" и лишние конструкции запутывают), но пока что все ваши ответы в точку, если извлечь из них суть)))